# How to disable light blue screen of unknown death in Windows 10 and get old BSOD back?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

When I have BSOD in Windows 10, I don't see any parameters anymore. I see only one symbolic bugcheck code and sad smiley.

Is it possible to configure BSOD to have all information again?

Comment: We are always glad to help, but you now have *four* questions open that are essentially related to the same original problem.  Are you sure that some of them couldn't have been combined?

Comment: Please regard all questions separate.

Comment: I understand that's what you want, and as I said before we are glad to help... but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: I am splitting big problem into small ones, because this gives more chances that somebody can answer.

Comment: look if this still works in Win10: http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-show-bsod-details-and-disable-sad-smiley-in-windows-8/

Comment: does the trick still work in Win10?

Comment: It didn't worked for me.